# C++ bidirectional dijkstra implementation very slow

Tags: c++, openstreetmap, dijkstra, bidirectional

I'm making my own implementation of bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm. I'm using it to do some research on routing in the Openstreetmaps (OSM) environment so I wanted to create my own implementation. The graph I am routing on is a 2d map of edges containing road segments from the OSM environment. It looks like this: `graph[ource_id][target_id] = Edgeinfo`.

I've tried it on a small demo graph and it seems to work fine, however when I try it on a (small) subset of the OSM data the computing time seems to explode and it can't even find small paths. I was wondering if my implementation is just very slow (hours for small paths) and could be done a lot faster or if I've made a mistake that I've missed in my code.

This are the main functions of my code:

main.cc

```
#include "graph.h"
#include "bidij.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    graph g;
    long long source_osm_id, target_osm_id;

    g.load();
    dijkstra d(g.myGraph);

    source_osm_id = 1;
    target_osm_id = 5;

    cout << "calculate route: " << endl;
    d.bidirectionaldijkstra(source_osm_id, target_osm_id);

    return 1;
}
```

graph.h

```
#ifndef ____graph__
#define ____graph__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct Edge
{
    double distance;
};

class graph {
  public:
    void load();
    map< long long, map <long long, Edge> > myGraph;
};

#endif
```

graph.cc

```
#include "graph.h"

void graph::load()
{
    Edge e;

    // edges from node 1
    e.distance = 7;
    this->myGraph[1][2] = e;

    e.distance = 9;
    this->myGraph[1][3] = e;

    e.distance = 14;
    this->myGraph[1][6] = e;

    // edges from node 2
    e.distance = 7;
    this->myGraph[2][1] = e;

    e.distance = 10;
    this->myGraph[2][3] = e;

    e.distance = 15;
    this->myGraph[2][4] = e;

    // edges from node 3
    e.distance = 2;
    this->myGraph[3][6] = e;

    e.distance = 9;
    this->myGraph[3][1] = e;

    e.distance = 10;
    this->myGraph[3][2] = e;

    e.distance = 11;
    this->myGraph[3][4] = e;

    // edges from node 4
    e.distance = 6;
    this->myGraph[4][5] = e;

    e.distance = 11;
    this->myGraph[4][3] = e;

    e.distance = 15;
    this->myGraph[4][2] = e;

    // edges from node 5
    e.distance = 9;
    this->myGraph[5][6] = e;

    e.distance = 6;
    this->myGraph[5][4] = e;

    // edges from node 6
    e.distance = 9;
    this->myGraph[6][5] = e;

    e.distance = 2;
    this->myGraph[6][3] = e;

    e.distance = 14;
    this->myGraph[6][1] = e;
}
```

bidij.h

```
#ifndef ____bidij__
#define ____bidij__

#include "graph.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct queueitem
{
    long long distance, osm_source_id, osm_target_id;
    queueitem * parentnode;
    queue<long long> * route;
};

class CompareQueueItems {
public:
    bool operator()(queueitem *t1, queueitem *t2){
        return (t1->distance > t2->distance);
    }
};

class dijkstra {
  public:
    dijkstra(map< long long, map <long long, Edge> > graph)
    {
        mu = numeric_limits<double>::max();
        myGraph = graph;
    }
    void bidirectionaldijkstra(long long, long long);
   private:
    double mu;
    long long v,w;
    map< long long, int> visited;
    map <long long, double> distancetable;
    map <long long, queueitem*> relaxednode;
    void exploration(queueitem*, int,priority_queue< queueitem*, vector< queueitem* >, CompareQueueItems> &);
    void print_route(queueitem * q, int direction);
    map< long long, map <long long, Edge> > myGraph;
};

#endif
```

bidij.cc

```
#include "bidij.h"

void dijkstra::exploration(queueitem *q, int direction ,priority_queue< queueitem*, vector< queueitem* >, CompareQueueItems> &pq)
{
    // all edges connected to v
    map <long long, Edge> edgev;
    map<long long, Edge>::const_iterator iv;
    queueitem *qtemp;

    edgev = myGraph[q->osm_source_id]; // edge v
    // scan each edge w around v (v,w)
    for(iv = edgev.begin(); iv != edgev.end();iv++)
    {
        if(visited[iv->first] == 0)
        {
            qtemp = new queueitem;
            qtemp->osm_source_id = iv->first;
            qtemp->parentnode = q;
            qtemp->distance = q->distance + iv->second.distance;
            qtemp->route = new queue<long long>(*q->route);
            pq.push(qtemp);

            // update shortest distance to w and add the node to a map so we can retrieve it later for printing the route
            if(distancetable[iv->first] > qtemp->distance){
                distancetable[iv->first] = qtemp->distance;
                relaxednode[iv->first] = qtemp;
            }
        } else if(visited[iv->first] != direction) {
            if((q->distance + iv->second.distance + distancetable[iv->first]) < mu)
            {
                // mu is the best path so far
                mu = (q->distance + iv->second.distance + distancetable[iv->first]);

                v = (direction == 1) ? q->osm_source_id : iv->first;
                w = (direction == 1) ? iv->first : q->osm_source_id;
            }
        }
    }
    visited[q->osm_source_id] = direction;

}

void dijkstra::print_route(queueitem * q, int direction)
{
    queueitem * qtemp = q, * new_root = NULL;

    if(direction == -1)
    {
        while(qtemp)
        {
            cout << qtemp->osm_source_id << ',';
            qtemp = qtemp->parentnode;
        }
    } else { // inverse
        while (qtemp) {
            queueitem* next = qtemp->parentnode;
            qtemp->parentnode = new_root;
            new_root = qtemp;
            qtemp = next;
        }
        while(new_root)
        {
            cout << new_root->osm_source_id << ',';
            new_root = new_root->parentnode;
        }
    }
}


void dijkstra::bidirectionaldijkstra(long long source, long long target)
{
    if(source == target)
    {
        cout << "Total distance: " << 0 << endl;
        cout << source << ',' << target << endl;
        return;
    }
    priority_queue< queueitem*, vector< queueitem* >, CompareQueueItems> frontq, reverseq;
    queueitem *qs, *qt;

    typedef map<long long, map <long long, Edge> >::iterator it_type;
    for(it_type iterator = myGraph.begin(); iterator != myGraph.end(); iterator++)
    {
        // set initial distances to infinity (or close to it)
        distancetable[iterator->first] = numeric_limits<double>::max();
        visited[iterator->first] = 0; // unvisited
    }

    int direction; // direction of the search

    // create queueitem from source node
    qs = new queueitem;
    qs->distance = 0.0f;
    qs->osm_source_id = source;
    qs->parentnode = NULL;
    qs->route = new queue<long long>;
    frontq.push(qs); // put source node on front priority queue
    distancetable[source] = 0.0f;
    relaxednode[source] = qs;

    // create queueitem from target node
    qt = new queueitem;
    qt->distance = 0.0f;
    qt->osm_source_id = target;
    qt->parentnode = NULL;
    qt->route = new queue<long long>;
    reverseq.push(qt); // put target node on reverse priority queue
    distancetable[target] = 0.0f;
    relaxednode[target] = qt;


    while(!frontq.empty() && !reverseq.empty())
    {
        qs = frontq.top();
        qt = reverseq.top();

        if(qs->distance + qt->distance >= mu)
        {
            cout << "Total distance: " << mu << endl;
            print_route(relaxednode[v],1);
            print_route(relaxednode[w],-1);
            return;
        } else {
            // explore from reverse queue
            if(qt->distance < qs->distance)
            {
                direction = -1;
                qt->route->push(qt->osm_source_id);
                exploration(qt,direction,reverseq);
                reverseq.pop();
            } else { // explore from front queue
                direction = 1;
                qs->route->push(qs->osm_source_id);
                exploration(qs,direction,frontq);
                frontq.pop();
            }
        }

    }
    cout << "notfound";
}
```

EDIT: added the full code to clear thing up.

The graph:
[image: The graph]

Comment: init `relaxednode` ... what's `v` and `w`? maybe you want to `pop` before calling `exploration`, since it can push other nodes?

Comment: relaxednode is a map which holds visited queueitems so in the end I could easily trace back and print the total route by following the parent nodes. v and w are the last nodes scanned from either side (front and reverse exploration) the path (v,w) combines the 2 paths from source to v in forward search and target to w in target search.

Comment: 1) I would suggest you not name your loop variable `iterator`.  2) What type is `visited`?  3) `qs->route = new queue<long long>;` Why is this a pointer when it could have just been an object? (thus making the `new` unnecessary)

Comment: @Blob911 You know that using `std::map::operator []` can be dangerous.  If that item is not in the map, the map will insert an empty entry into it.  So your map is potentially being changed without you knowing it.  Also, it would also help if you posted a full, but small example program.

Comment: visited is of type map< long long, int> visited; long long to hold the big id's I need to put in there. `int = 0` means unvisited, `-1` means visited in the reverse direction, 1 means visited in the forward direction.

Comment: I ran your code, and other than the memory leaks in your code, the program completes with the output: `calculate route: ` `Total distance: 20`  `1,3,6,5,`  Maybe you should debug your code and check that you are not using uninitialized variables.  I used Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I did some debugging / fixing memory leaks and started testing my code on my laptop (OSX) and it works perfectly on my big data set. However exactly the same code and dataset produce a different result on my desktop (windows).